# An error occurred while executing subprocess cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, web, ngcordova

I'm taking an IONIC + Angular course, and I'm having a little problem uploading the apk project to my cell phone, I'm using cordova.
As soon as I connect the cell to the computer and it's time to run the command "ionic cordova run android" it gives some errors, it could be the versions that I have installed on my computer, but I don't have enough knowledge to be sure of that, could help me?

1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkcfY.png)
2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkJci.png)

I've tried to run several commands that I've searched on the net but I haven't had good results, it hangs at the very end

I looked for some solutions on the net but it still doesn't work, I think it's something related to the installed versions

Comment: Delete node-modules, android, dist folder and re-build.  Try with --verbose

Comment: Thanks for answering, thaI will delete the node_modules, resources and platform folder and run the command ionic cordova run android --verbose (I did not find the dist folder, I will post below how my project is)

Comment: Dist folder is generatet. npm run build

Comment: C:\PROJETOS IONIC\prestesApp>npm run build --verbose
...
> prestesApp@0.0.1 build
> ng build
You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.
npm verb exit 2
npm verb code 2

Comment: ionic build 
Foloew the link https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/build/

Comment: I posted an image just below the error that is giving now in gradle

Answer (score 1):

This is because the path to Android Sdk is not set correctly. Please check the correct path for Sdk, tools, platform-tools, emulator and Android build-tools.

Please, realize that the configuration recommended for Ionic has changed a bit. Now the notation recommended is as follows:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/username/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/username/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
```

In Linux or Mac OS X configure the path into the ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools
```

At the end, after save the configuration dont forget to do the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or as your case

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

For the Windows users check the global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an image just below the error that is giving now in gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdica.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).